Tournure idiomatique au restaurant
Bonjour !
Je me demande comment on pourrait répondre négativement à la question “Pour le dessert, je vous donne la carte ?” dans un restaurant français. Est-ce qu’on pourrait dire quelque chose dans le genre suivant ? :

“Non, merci, nous sommes satisfaits.” >


“Non, merci, nous allons nous contenter de cela.”>


Notez bien que vous pouvez répondre avec tous les mots de la langue, et pour dire ce que vous voulez. Il n'est pas forcément besoin de chercher "la" réponse "type", qui n'existe de toute façon probablement pas.

Je ne dirais ni l'une ni l'autre. Satisfaits est un peu bizarre dans ce contexte. On pourrait éventuellement dire nous sommes rassasiés mais c'est trop soutenu.
J'éviterais aussi nous allons nous contenter de cela qui est aussi trop soutenu et en plus risque d'être mal interprété. Se contenter de quelque chose signifie qu'on est pas exigeant et donc signifier que le repas servi n'était pas très bon et qu'on ne souhaite pas continuer.
Voici quelques réponses possibles :

Non merci.  (neutre)
Non merci, on a terminé.  (neutre)
Non, pas de dessert, merci.  (neutre)
Non merci, l'addition s'il vous plait.  (neutre, pressé)
Non merci, on a bien mangé (mais on arrête là).  (positif)
Non merci, c'était très bon (mais on arrête là).  (positif)
Non merci, on doit y aller.  (neutre, pressé)

Le ton employé peut bien sûr affecter l'impression donnée par la réponse, un non merci sec peut être signe d'insatisfaction, au contraire d'un non merci avec un sourire.
Ce ne sont que des exemples et on peut très bien dire tout autre chose comme @Frank l'a dit en commentaire. Ce qui reste cependant assez codifié est le non merci qu'on prononce d'une traite, comme s'il s'agissait d'un seul mot "nonmerci". Un non tout seul pourrait être mal perçu, surtout venant de francophones.
Il ne faut surtout pas dire Je suis plein à l'image de l'I'm full qu'on peut entendre en anglais1. Les serveurs risquent de se tordre de rire. Je suis plein peut signifier qu'on a trop bu d'alcool ou alors, on s'assimile à une chose qu'on remplit comme un sac, un réservoir, ce qui n'est pas du tout élégant et ne fait pas honneur à la cuisine servie. Le pire serait de dire Je suis pleine qui pourrait vouloir dire qu'on est une femelle animale gravide (qui attend des petits).
1 Voir aussi ELU

Et aussi : Non merci, nous ne prendrons pas de dessert.

Et aussi: non merci. Il n'y a pas de formule consacrée :-)

@Graffito Ok sauf la 1ère personne du pluriel qui me semble trop soutenue à l'oral. Nous ne prendrons pas [...] m'évoque plus une réplique de théâtre qu'un dialogue avec un serveur.

Dans ce cas, "on ne prendra pas de dessert" fait plus familier (les Anglo-Saxons diraient colloquial);

@Graffito Pas seulement familier mais dans la plupart des registres. Le nous + 1ère pers. du pluriel a quasiment disparu de l'oral spontané. Ce qui peut être considéré comme familier, c'est On prendra pas de dessert.

« Satisfait » ne convient pas tout simplement parce que dans ce contexte ce serait  une remarque qui porte sur la qualité du service et des mets commandés. Si, par exemple, donnée la présence d'un client plus ou moins important à l'une des tables, le directeur de l'hôtel ou du restaurant venait  demander à ce client si le service avait répondu à ses exigences, alors « Nous sommes [(plusieurs personnes]/Je suis [une seule personne] satisfait(s). » conviendrait, cette réponse étant suffisante mais peu chaleureuse, et un client qui apprécie son restaurant ajouterait certainement un compliment à cette réplique de base.
« Se contenter » exprime la résignation suite à un problème personnel (dans ce cas)—s'il faut attendre un quart d'heure parce que les truites n'ont pas été livrées à temps, le client peut se contenter de saumon, ce n'est plus un problème personnel— : on n'a pas trop d'argent (ça arrive), on est légèrement indisposé ce jour-là (ça arrive, et pas nécessairement parce que le hors d'œuvre aurait été aigre), on a abusé du gratin et on pense à sa ligne (ça arrive aussi), on est franchement déçu par la nourriture dans ce restaurant et on pense, comme on dit très familièrement, qu'il est temps d'arrêter les frais (pas de dessert) ; aucun de ces problèmes (il y en a d'autres de semblables) ne concerne le personnel du restaurant, et le dernier n'est généralement pas à discuter avec le personnel ou la direction à moins que le repas ait été exécrable. Tous ces petits ennuis sont des choses dont on ne parle pas avec les gens sans entretenir avec eux des relations assez familières ;      dire « on se contentera » laisse supposer un des problèmes de la sorte mentionnée ci-dessus : un garçon d'hôtel ne manquera pas de comprendre que son client, si celui-ci est français, bien sûr, n'est pas conscient de convenances sociales des plus raffinées, ou pour le moins qu'il pèche par négligence ou ignorance de certaines. Le seul fait de formuler une résignation appelle une explication, celle-ci ne pouvant être qu'un problème personnel. Voilà, à mon avis pourquoi la seconde possibilité ne convient pas non plus.
Les possibilités de réponse sont nombreuses et dépendent aussi de circonstances particulière.

Non, merci, ce sera tout.

Non, merci, aujourd'hui nous ne prendrons pas de dessert.

J'ai terminé (mon repas), l'addition je vous prie.

Non, merci, veuillez nous apporter l'addition.

Non, merci, l'addition s'il vous plait.

Non, merci, nous avons/on a terminé.

Non, merci, nous passerons tout de suite au café.

Non, merci, je crois que ce sera tout [et vous pouvez vous tourner vers vos convives, si vous en avez, et demander leur approbation, puis conclure] nous prendrons seulement une fraise à la crème pour ce monsieur(, qui en raffole).

Non, merci, on doit y aller (Quand vous vous trouvez dans la petite gargote au coin de la rue, où vous appelez tous les garçons par leur prénom)


Ne pas dire

Non, merci, on a bien mangé. (Votre satisfaction intérieure  et le niveau de votre satiété ne concernent pas le personnel ; c'est comme si vous lui parliez de la pluie et du beau temps. Au plus, vous pouvez faire  des compliments sur la qualité des préparations, mais ce n'est pas le moment, et les clients ne font pas souvent cela.)

J'ai vu dans la réponse précédente une remarque sur l'habitude anglo-saxonne de dire avec satisfaction à la fin d'un repas « I'm full », et je crois pouvoir ajouter certaines choses. Dans l'esprit de l'homme de la rue français, les remarques à l'effet d'une confusion avec les états d'ébriété et de grossesse sont certes possibles (et ne fait rire que les faibles d'esprit), mais il ne faut pas voir là une raison majeure pour éviter (absolument) de dire « Je suis plein ! » à la fin d'un repas. La raison majeure, celle qui  « active » l'esprit d'une personne cultivée en France, c'est grosso modo celle que l'on trouve dans la réponse précédente, c'est le rejet de l'idée d'une assimilation en disant cela à, je cite, «  une chose qu'on remplit comme un sac, un réservoir  », ce qui est considéré comme, je cite, « pas du tout élégant ». On peut bien dire « Nous sommes rassasiés », et lorsqu'on est rassasié à l'excès « J'ai trop mangé » (formes toutes deux de bon gout), et à n'en pas douter on exprime par cela le même état psycho-physiologique qui est exprimé par « I am full », mais les français se sont senti le besoin de devoir associer  l'idée d'être « plein » à l'acte d'une vache qui va à l'abreuvoir une fois par jour et s'astreint à l'opération d'une longue et ininterrompue submersion de son museau dans l'eau dans un processus d'ingurgitation continue jusqu'à ce que le « niveau » dans son estomac lui indique qu'il n'en faut pas plus, autrement dit jusqu'au point où son estomac lui dit qu'il est plein, ou en d'autres termes encore, qu'elle est pleine (Je n'en dirais pas tant de la pauvre vache et je dirais qu'elle a assez bu, mais c'est une autre histoire.).
De cette « psychologie » est née l'aversion pour l'expression « être plein », mais il n'est pas certain que tout individu qui nourrit cette aversion soit conscient de son origine culturelle.

Il m'arrive souvent de parler de la pluie et du beau temps avec le personnel des restaurants. Je n'y vois rien de répréhensible et ceux qui rient après une blague ne sont pas des faibles d'esprit.

@jlliagre Vous les connaissez peut-être un peu, mais on ne parle pas de cas-là.  De toute façon, je ne vais pas jusqu'à parler de choses répréhensibles, pas du tout // Si j'entendais un étranger qui dise « Je suis plein(e) » après avoir suffisamment ou trop mangé, j'identifierais d'abord le manque d'idiomaticité, et ne verrais rien d'amusant en allant chercher midi à quatorze heures avec des réflexions grossières.  Beaucoup de gens ont cette attitude,  De plus, aucune plaisanterie n'est faite ; qui plaisante ? Vous pouvez dire ça ?

J'ai bien plus souvent entendu je suis plein de la part de francophones qui le disaient pour rire. Je ne crois même pas l'avoir entendu d'anglophones, en tout cas jamais quand ils s'adressaient à un serveur. D'autre part, tu identifies plus facilement le manque d'idiomaticité parce que tu es bilingue et que tu connais l'expression anglaise mais même en la connaissant, je trouve l'expression très amusante, il n'y a rien de mal à ça.

@jlliagre Oui, ça peut faire sourire de voir qu'un étranger crois dire ce qui convient alors qu'il se trompe ; je peux admettre un tel comportement tant qu'il n'est pas poussé à l'excès.

Tu m'as mal lu, ce sont des francophones qui le disent comme ils disent/on dit finger in the nose, c'est pour rire. On ne se moque de personne sinon de nous-mêmes.

@jlliagre Tous les sourires ne sont pas moqueurs, loin de là.
